# Don't let the Stack Exchange network spoil my favourite TV series

Tags: discussion

This just popped up in my hot network questions when looking for programming answers:

[Why did Jon Snow make him the hand of the king?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77905/why-did-jon-snow-make-him-the-hand-of-the-king)

I haven't started watching series 7 yet and cant un-see this now. I've only just joined this site to post this so I don't know what sort of community guidelines are in place but can I suggest a rule against this sort of title.

Comment: We don't use spoilers in title but it is allowed in the body. And the title of the said question does not appear to be a spoiler.

Comment: @AJ It did have a spoiler before it was edited.

Comment: It's still a spoiler with its current title. if Jon Snow can appoint someone as hand of the king then he must now be the king. If iv'e misunderstood that feel free to not correct me on it. I haven't read the full question

Comment: I do not know anything about the series. but if it is spoiler it should be flagged. If you want to filter S.E. Movies from your Hot-network-questions then there is in-depth Meta for this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites

Comment: great thanks for the link @Paharet

Comment: Honestly rdans - the event described certainly didn't happen in S7 ..... if it happened it was in S6.

Comment: thanks @iandotkelly - probably need a catch up :)

Answer (score 1):

Iv'e "solved" it for now by using a chrome plugin called cjs to run a custom script on stackoverflow.com pages. The script is the below line which hides the hot network questions from me.

```
$("#hot-network-questions").hide();
```